# How to apply linear cryptanalysis to PRESENT?

Tags: implementation, linear-cryptanalysis, present

Can someone help me implement linear cryptanalysis of the [PRESENT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESENT_%28cipher%29) block cipher?
How should I start with 64 bits of plaintext and 80 bits of key?

Comment: Your question seems quite broad to me, and you might want to narrow it down a bit. While I might be wrong, I don't *think* anyone's likely to post a complete walkthrough of cryptanalysing PRESENT here, and in any case, it might not even fit in our answer length limit. However, if you could tell us how much you've figured out on your own, and where specifically you're getting stuck, that might increase your chance of getting useful answers.

Comment: Ps. You might find [this paper](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Publications/jcho/present_lc_v3.pdf) useful to skim, and maybe [this](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~howard/PAPERS/ldc_tutorial.pdf) as well.

Comment: In terms of programming how should i apply zero correlation cryptanalysis or on how many no. of rounds it can be applied? how can we decide that?

Comment: can you tell me how can we apply a attack on 64 bits of data. i.e. 2 to the power of 64 bits. how can it be done in terms of programming.